# Compute the coefficients of the following differential equation

Tags: hilbert-spaces, time-series, mean-square-error

Let $X,Y_1,Y_2$ be elements of the Hilbert space $L²$, and $Y$ is to be approximated by

$$\hat{Y}=aX_1+bX_2$$

which minimizes the mean squared error

$$MSE:=\mathbb{E}|Y-\hat{Y}|^2.$$

Now I have to find $a$ and $b$.

What have I done? I know that for $X,Y\in L²$ the mean $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\langle X,Y\rangle.$ First, I've written the MSE into

$$MSE=\mathbb{E}Y^2+a^2\mathbb{E}X_1^2+b^2\mathbb{E}X_2^2-2(a\mathbb{E}(YX_1)+b\mathbb{E}(YX_2))+2ab\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)$$

Second, I've derivatived $MSE$ with respect to $a$ and $b$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial MSE}{\partial a}&=2a\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)-2\mathbb{E}(YX_1)+2b\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)=0\\
\frac{\partial MSE}{\partial b}&=2b\mathbb{E}(X_2^2)-2\mathbb{E}(YX_2)+2a\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)=0
\end{align*}
This is equal to
\begin{align*}
a\mathbb{E}X_1^2+b\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2) &= \mathbb{E}(YX_1)\\
a\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)+b\mathbb{E}X_2^2 &=\mathbb{E}(YX_2).
\end{align*}
**UPDATE:**

Next, I form the above linear system into a matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}X_1^2 & \mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)\\
\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2) & \mathbb{E}X_2^2
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ b
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}(YX_1)\\
\mathbb{E}(YX_2)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then, after building the inverse, I get my solutions, i.e.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ b
\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}X_1^2\mathbb{E}X_2^2-\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}X_2^2 & - \mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)\\
-\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2) & \mathbb{E}X_1^2
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}(YX_1)\\
\mathbb{E}(YX_2)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So, I get
$$
\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{\mathbb{E}X_2^2\mathbb{E}(YX_1)-\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)\mathbb{E}(YX_2)}{\mathbb{E}X_1^2\mathbb{E}X_2^2-\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)^2}\\
b &= \frac{\mathbb{E}X_1^2\mathbb{E}(YX_2)-\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)\mathbb{E}(YX_1)}{\mathbb{E}X_1^2\mathbb{E}X_2^2-\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)^2}
\end{align*}
$$